# SQL insert into stored procedure phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have the following code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE userAanmaken
(    
IN domeinNummer INT(11),
IN gebruikerNaam VARCHAR(45),
IN gebruikerPass VARCHAR(45),
IN gebruikerEmail VARCHAR(45),
IN gebruikerVN VARCHAR(50),
IN gebruikerTV VARCHAR(10),
IN gebruikerAN VARCHAR(50),
IN gebruikerGS VARCHAR(1),
IN gebruikerOL VARCHAR(30),
IN gebruikerGD DATE
)



BEGIN 

DECLARE lastID INT

INSERT INTO Gebruiker(Domein_idDomeint) 
VALUES (domeinNummer);

SET lastId=LAST_INSERT_ID()

INSERT INTO Inlog (Gebruiker_idGebruiker,UserName,UserPass)
VALUES (lastId,gebruikerNaam,gebruikerPass);

INSERT INTO GGevens (Gebruiker_idGebruiker,Email,Voornaam,Tussenvoeg,Achternaam,Geslacht,Opleiding,GebDatum)
VALUES (lastId,gebruikerEmail,gebruikerVN,gebruikerTV,gebruikerAN,gebruikerGS,gebruikerOL,gebruikerGD);
END;
```

But it returns with the error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'INSERT INTO Gebruiker(Domein_idDomeint) VALUES (domeinNummer)'
>   at line 21 Nieuw phpMyAdmin-scherm openen

I is a simple insert into statement... what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is `Domein_idDomeint` one column name?

Comment: Yes :-) it looks like this: http://i.imgur.com/SalSfQh.png

Comment: Nope: http://i.imgur.com/yjYX7vU.png

Comment: ok first thing when create stored procedure change delimiter (scheidingsteken) to something else than semicolon, let's say $$ and at the last line in stored procedure is END$$ not END;

Comment: Same error: http://i.imgur.com/dgdUFz0.png

Comment: No, no you use semicolon in stored procedure as before only the last line of stored procedure that last delimiter should be $$. So at the end of DECLARE lastID INT; use semicolon also at the end of SET and INSERT statement but at the end of procedure last line is END$$... Sorry for my english hope you understand me now...

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a semicolon after

```
DECLARE lastID INT
```

And also

```
SET lastId=LAST_INSERT_ID()
```

Comment: See comment above, when i do enter a semicolon it gives me this error: http://i.imgur.com/yjYX7vU.png